# Bison/Flex If statements

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I'm attempting to make a parser that can handle if else statements. I currently have the following code for my bison.y file:

```
ifstate: IF_TOKEN LPARENT compare RPARENT statement ENDIF_TOKEN
    | IF_TOKEN LPARENT compare RPARENT statement else
;

else: ELSE_TOKEN statement ENDIF_TOKEN
    | ELSEIF_TOKEN LPARENT compare RPARENT statement ENDIF_TOKEN
    | ELSEIF_TOKEN LPARENT compare RPARENT statement else
;
```

Here i have compare returning a string that is true or false. and statements is any statement (from addition to assignments to more if statements). However i don't know how to only do the statements when that if is true.

Comment: Your main question is close to unanswerable because of a lack of context.  The comparison will be performed at runtime, unless the condition is constant and you have code that can detect that.  How are you generating any code?  There's no indication, so there's no way we can help you with how to generate the code differently for handling this.  ISTR that it is modestly messy generating code for such statements — working out where to send the interpreter after the actions in the statement are complete is fiddly given that you don't yet know where the ENDIF will be, etc. It can be done, though.

Answer (score 0):

An `if` statement compiles into pseudo-code of the form:

```
    ; set up the condition 
    TEST
    BRANCH FALSE $1
    ; body of 'if' statement
$1: ; next statement
```

An `if/else` statement:

```
    ; set up the condition 
    TEST
    BRANCH FALSE $1
    ; body of 'if' statement
    BRANCH $2
$1:  ; // body of 'else' statement
$2: ; next statement
```